# Extract two values between square brackets an get the results in two different columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, t-sql

I have in a column some Names and then square brackets with some numbers and letters inside.
How can I extract two values between square brackets and get the results in two different columns?

I start from the Column 'NAME' with the value 'XCDRT [20.9 kd]'

```
--NAME--
XCDRT [20.9 kd]
qwer [12.234 r.t.]
```

and I would like to get 3 columns with the values in different columns

```
-- NAME--- NAME 1--- NAME 2---
--XCDRT----  20.9-------- kd----
--qwer----- 12.234-------- r.t.-----
```

Is there a function for such a problem?

I tried to split the value but I don't get the results that I need.

Comment: See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055) and how to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: *"I tried to split the value but I don't get the results that I need."* You appear to have forgotten to include that attempts in your question.

Answer (score 3):

With a bit of JSON and a CROSS APPLY (or two)

Cross Apply B will split/parse the string

Cross Apply C will create JSON to be consumed.

This will also support N groups of 3

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Name] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('XCDRT [20.9 kd] qwer [12.234 r.t.]')
 
Select [Name]  = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[0]')
      ,[Name1] = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[1]')
      ,[Name2] = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[2]')
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply string_split([Name],']') B
 Cross Apply ( values ('["'+replace(string_escape(trim(replace(B.Value,'[','')),'json'),' ','","')+'"]') ) C(JS)
 Where B.value<>''
```

**Results**

```
Name    Name1   Name2
XCDRT   20.9    kd
qwer    12.234  r.t.
```

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative solution, if you are on a bleeding edge version of the SQL Server data engine, then you make use of `STRING_SPLIT` and it's (new) ability to return the ordinal position of a value. Then, with some conditional aggregation, you can unpivot the results:

```sql
SELECT TRIM(MAX(CASE N.ordinal WHEN 1 THEN N.[value] END)) AS [Name],
       TRIM(MAX(CASE N.ordinal WHEN 2 THEN LEFT(N.[value], CHARINDEX(' ',N.[value] + ' ')) END)) AS [Name1],
       TRIM(MAX(CASE N.ordinal WHEN 2 THEN NULLIF(STUFF(N.[value], 1, CHARINDEX(' ',N.[value] + ' '),''),'') END)) AS [Name2]
FROM (VALUES('XCDRT [20.9 kd] qwer [12.234 r.t.]'))V([NAME])
     CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(V.[NAME],']',1) R
     CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(R.[value],'[',1) N
WHERE R.[value] != ''
GROUP BY V.[NAME],
         R.ordinal;
```

The `TRIM`s and `NULLIF` are there to "tidy" the values,  as you'd have leading whitespace and incase you don't have a value for `Name2`.